# Animation support in front-end MV* frameworks

Tags: angularjs, animation, ember.js, polymer, reactjs

Which front-end javascript MV* framework would you recommend for an animation heavy website (animated page elements, transitions, parallax scrolling etc.)? My first impression is that it's easiest (spending least time, achieving effect with most concise code, having best documentation) to do in angular.js. What were your experiences?

P.S.
The choice of tags is of course limited to 5, so if anybody could suggest any other framework I would be interested in that as well.

Comment: I would avoid Reacjs for this particular case. It's an awesome framework in general, but since you work with a virtual DOM you need to render everything once before you can access elements in the real DOM. This means to be able to get height, width, position, etc. which you might want to use when animating, you need to render first and then use getDOMNode or utilize refs to access those properties.

Comment: React.js would be a good choice for transitions-based sites though. The problem with most frameworks is that they render templates as strings, then paste them wholesale into the DOM: you have to chuck a huge slab of content in, then animate it. But react deals with things as granularly as it can: if the content change amounts to different text in a <p> tag and a class change, it'll change the text node and the classList, preserving the DOM node and allowing whatever transitions to occur without interruption.

Answer (score 2):

I work on the Chrome team and graphics performance is often something that needs particular care. There's ultimately a trade-off between simplicity (e.g how much a framework or library can do for you) vs. how close to the grain you stay in order to keep the experience of your animations fast. Ideally, you should try to keep as much of your animation related code directly in CSS rather than having JS (e.g a directive or library) trigger those animations for you. I would in general remember that (cross-browser) the browser can animate 4 things quite cheaply (position, scale, rotation and opacity) for you. Try to use these where possible. I would also take a look at some of the examples in http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/ as you'd be surprised how far you can get without making animations part of your reasoning for selecting an MVC framework.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the combination of angularjs and angular-ui (twitter bootstrap in angular) great for building in ui animations. I can highly recommend it.

Working with the ngAnimate module works really nicely and provide very user friendly interfaces.

For a simple starter guide, this is great

http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css

And for a more comprehensive guide try

http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html